# How to get $\theta$ alone in $\sin2(\theta)$?

Tags: geometry, physics

$\sin2 \theta = (R \sin \phi)/2\cdot L$

I understand that the double angle formula brings $\sin2 \theta = 2\sin\theta \cos \theta$, however, I don't understand how to get $\theta$ alone on one side of the equation.

Comment: Did you mean $\dfrac{R\sin\varphi} 2 \cdot L$ or $\dfrac{R\sin\varphi}{2L} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Do you want $\theta$ in place of$ \sin\theta$ ??

Comment: Take the inverse sine of the RHS and divide by 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sin(2\theta) & = (\cdots\cdots\cdots) \\[10pt]
2\theta & = \arcsin(\cdots\cdots\cdots) \\[10pt]
\theta & = \frac 1 2 \arcsin(\cdots\cdots\cdots)
\end{align}

Comment: Ha ha.. You didn't even wait for confirmation. +1 if this is what he meant.

Comment: Of course this is only one possible $\theta$: there are others, because $\sin(\pi - 2\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$ and $\sin(2\theta + 2 \pi) = \sin(2\theta)$.